# iOS 14 broke my Shortcut

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a shortcut that I created in 2019 and it stopped working after iOS 14 upgrade. The specific part that stopped working is the display at the end of some calculations. No numbers are shown, only the text, like "your answer is: "  but the resulting numeric value is not shown. So, it would seem the shortcut isn't using the variables, I mean it is not like I see "your answer is: 0" the space where the number/variable should be is blank.

How can I begin to debug this?

Comment: Have you tested each of the variables? If the calculation is dividing by 0 then it may well default to blank, you have to check each step.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose that is part of my question, how do I test the variables? at the end of the shortcut there's a notification that prints out the variables, but as I mentioned nothing shows up as far as numeric values. Can you recommend an environment to debug other than editing the shortcut on the iPhone itself? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the environment you used to create it?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help.
I had to go through and re-assign all of the fall-thru variables that I was using. not sure if they were always called magic-variables, but after conversion to ios14 all of my formulas had only "Number" in where I had previously used the result from the previous operation. Once I assigned all of the "Number"s to real values, everything worked again.